# Confirmation email is not populating on Paypal (pay by card) with sage integration

Tags: opayo

I have integrated sagepay with Asp MVC my application by using direct integration,and i am sending details like product name,product detail,amount ,CustomerEmail means all field which need but when i am selecting paypal in sagepay page and selecting Pay with Guest user means by using paypal i want to make payment by card,the form where i have to fill card details,shipping address,and also Customer Email and contact number,address is displaying but contact number and Customer email is not auto populating in form...for sending data to sagepay i have used below code:

```
var data = "VendorTxCode=" + invoiceDetails.InvoiceNumber;
                       // data += "&Amount=" + Math.Round((feeAmount+taxAmount),2);
                        data += "&Amount=" + Math.Round(feeAmount, 2);
                        data += "&Currency=" + CurrencyCode;
                        data += "&Description=" + eventname;
                        data += "&CustomerName=" + invoiceDetails.ebecs_PrimaryContact.Name + "";
                    data += "&CustomerEMail=" + email;
                    data += "&BillingSurname=" + surname;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Sage Pay sends the customer email and contact number to Pay Pal so I would expect this to be the reason why the information is not displaying.

Comment: Thanks Neil for giving reply,I am also thinking like you,but this issue is coming only if I am selecting the option "pay with card" or "Pay with Guest User" and if i am trying to make payment using paypal account with sagepay then sagepay is sending customer email and contact number.